# Piping stream to ffmpeg via forked process stdin

Tags: c, linux, ffmpeg

I am piping data from my raspberry pi camera to ffmpeg to convert them into an mp4 stream. I do so not with libavformat/libavformat but I call `ffmpeg` directly like this:

```
        context->ffmpeg_process = utils::launch_subprocess(
                "ffmpeg",
                {"-f", "rawvideo", "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", "-s", "1920x1080", "-r", "30", "-i", "-", "-c", "libx264", "-f", "mp4", "-movflags", "frag_keyframe+empty_moov", "-", "-loglevel", "trace"}
        );
```

This is my wrapper around fork and exec like this:

```
        const auto child = fork();
        if(child == 0) {
            if (dup2(stdin_pipe[PIPE_READ], STDIN_FILENO) == -1) {
                exit(errno);
            }

            // same for stdout and sterr

            execvp(command.c_str(), proc_args);
            exit(errno);
        } else if(child > 0) {
            // same for stdout and stderr
            ret_process.stdin_pipe = stdin_pipe[PIPE_WRITE];
        }
```

Now I have a callback that is called by the raspberry pi camera:

```
    void CameraHandler::handle_camera_frame(const std::vector<uint8_t> &data, std::size_t size) {
        FILE* f = fopen("output.yuv4", "ab");
        fwrite(data.data(), 1, size, f);
        fclose(f);

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l{_listener_lock};
        for (const auto &listener : _data_listeners) {
            std::size_t written = 0;
            while (written < size) {
                const auto num_written = write(listener->ffmpeg_process.stdin_pipe, data.data() + written, size - written);
                written += num_written;
                if(num_written < 0) {
                    log->error("Broken stdin pipe");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I deliberately append every frame to a file because I am running the exact same command as above (with `cat output.yuv4 | ffmpeg ... > output4.mp4` to cross check).

Now I can see that I am reading some data from my camera and pushing it to the ffmpeg process. But already after the first read ffmpeg complains, that the input data is invalid:

```
[2019-11-06 20:08:04.010] [11872:11932] [carpi::data::CameraHandler] [info] Launched ffmpeg process. PID: 11933, error: 0
[2019-11-06 20:08:04.014] [11872:11932] [carpi::video::RawCameraStream] [info] Camera dimension: 1920/1080
ffmpeg version 4.1.4-1+rpt1~deb10u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1+rpt1~deb10u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --arch=arm --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url -.
Applying option pix_fmt (set pixel format) with argument yuv420p.
Applying option s (set frame size (WxH or abbreviation)) with argument 1920x1080.
Applying option r (set frame rate (Hz value, fraction or abbreviation)) with argument 30.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: -.
[NULL @ 0xcd02d0] Opening 'pipe:' for reading
[pipe @ 0xcd0b50] Setting default whitelist 'crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0xcd8d50] Statistics: 1048576 bytes read, 0 seeks
pipe:: Invalid data found when processing input
```

I am now confused. This is literally the same as I am `fwrite`ing and then piping from the file. Is there something wrong with my `write`?

Comment: What happened when you e.g. switched out `ffmpeg` for `dd of=mydump` to inspect the data being written?

Comment: While not actually showing the problem this pointed me into the right direction. My `launch_subprocess` was using `execvp` but did not replicate the file being executed (`ffmpeg`) as the first argument. Now it works!